Problems with OCR1B on Atmega328p
Trying to control 4 servos (SG90) using 4 pots on an arduino nano and the one connected to OC1B keeps having problems, with bits of jittering and it just not moving correctly (occasionally spinning), even when using the same code as for OC1A. I use the following function to initialize it
void initPWM1FastTopAB(uint8_t resetorno, uint8_t inverted, uint16_t prescaler, uint16_t top){
    
    DDRB |= (1<<DDB1) | (1<<DDB2);
    
    if (resetorno) { 
        TCCR1A = 0;
    TCCR1B = 0;}
    
    TCCR1C = 0;
    
    TCCR1A |= ((1<<COM1A1) | (1<<COM1B1)); 
    
    if (inverted) {TCCR1A |= ((1<<COM1A0) | (1<<COM1B0));}

    
    TCCR1A |= (1<<WGM13)|(1<<WGM12)|(1<<WGM11);
    
    //Prescaler
    
    switch(prescaler) {
        case 1: TCCR1B |= (1<<CS10);
        break;
        
        case 8: TCCR1B |= (1<<CS11);
        break;
        
        case 64: TCCR1B |= (1<<CS11)|(1<<CS10);
        break;
        
        case 256: TCCR1B |= (1<<CS12);
        break;
        
        case 1024: TCCR1B |= (1<<CS12)|(1<<CS10);
        break;
        
    }
    
    ICR1 = top;
    
    }

Then in my main code I set up with this:
#define F_CPU 1000000
...
void setup(void)
{
    cli();
    
    // Control prescaler
    CLKPR = (0b10000000); 
    CLKPR = (0x03); 

    
    PCICR = (0b00000010);
    PCMSK1 = (1<<PCINT8) | (1<<PCINT9) | (1<<PCINT10) | (1<<PCINT11); //Interrupts on C0 - C3
    PORTC = (1<<PORTC0) | (1<<PORTC1) | (1<<PORTC2) | (1<<PORTC3); //Pullup
    DDRC = 0;

    
    initPWM1FastTopAB(reset, no_invertido, 8, 2499); 
    initPWM0FastA(reset, no_invertido, 256);
    initPWM0FastB(no_reset, no_invertido, 256);
    initPWM2FastB(reset, no_invertido, 256);
    
    
    /*TCCR2A = 0;
    TCCR2B = 0;
    TCCR2A |= 
    TCCR2B |= 0b00000110; //Prescaler 256
    TIMSK2 = 0x01; //Overflow y compare A interrupt
    TCNT2 = timer2reset; 
    //OCR2A = 128;
    //DDRB |= (1<<DDB2);*/

    DDRD |= 0b10010100; 
    
    
    initADC();
    
    sei();
}

Use the following in the main loop
for (int i = 4; i < 8; i++) {
        ADCChannel = i; ki bh
        convertADC(i);
        _delay_ms(300);
        }

And use this function to start movement in the ADC interrupt
void moveServos(uint16_t servo1, uint16_t servo2, uint16_t servo3, uint16_t servo4) { 
    uint16_t ADCRT1 = servo1 + 65;
    updateDutyCycle1A(ADCRT1);  
    
    uint16_t ADCRT2 = servo2 + 65;
    updateDutyCycle1B(ADCRT2);
    
    uint8_t ADCRT3 = servo3/16 + 4;
    updateDutyCycle0A(ADCRT3);
    
    uint8_t ADCRT4 = servo4/16 + 4;
    updateDutyCycle0B(ADCRT4);
    
}

I know it's not the ADC, because if I switch the pins that give info for OCR1A and OCR1B it works fine with the other channel. I also sometimes have the issue that when pressing buttons it causes the servos to move in strange directions

Have you switched potentiometers to rule out whether the wiper is making good contact? (Or did you basically do this with the channel swap?)

I've done both (swapping the physical pots and the channel swap)

Arduino initializes the timers, and uses one of them (I think Timer1) for stuff like time bookkeeping. What if you adapt the program not to use any Arduino code, and build it standalone?

I’m using an Arduino nano but I’m not using the Arduino IDE or any code from it

Please take the waveform of the output with an oscilloscope. If it is the firmware, you should see respective pulse widths, but if the pulse width is constant, it is your hardware. -- Additionally you can fix the pulse width for this output in firmware and watch the servo.

I just gave up and used Timer2 instead. Sucks to lose the precision but I simply couldn't figure out why it wasn't working
